# ArcGIS Pro legend changes after export, What you see is not what you get

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend

I have a map made in ArcGIS Pro v2.7.  After export I noticed that the legend has changes its location and the map frame (named *layers*) appears in the exported PNGs legend.  This also happens when exporting to PDF but apparently there is a problem with [Grid lines display in PDFs exported from ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022758).

Here is a screenshot of the map in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the output file.

[image]

Fussing with the legend properties does not seem to have an affect on the output.

[image]

How do you get a legend in ArcGIS Pro v2.7 to export like it looks in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: I've never experienced that behaviour which suggests to me a corrupt document? Try a new blank project with some other dataset and see if the problem is replicated under a simple frame and legend layout scenario.  If it does replicate then it would suggest maybe the application has become corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but I recently ran into this issue as well. I am using ArcGIS Pro v2.9. I was able to resolve the legend adding "Layer" after exporting to .pdf.

I started by selecting all of my legend items > format legend > legend items "Show Properties" > ensure that "Layer name" is unselected.

This is what worked for me. I am not sure if it will work for all cases.